# Server tag not well formed for ASP DropDownList for ItemTemplate

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Company Membership">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:DropDownList id="ddlCompanyMembership" runat="server" class="form-control" onchange="verifyUser('<%# ((DataRowView)Container.DataItem)["CCMP_CODE"].ToString() %>');" />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

I can't seem to build this properly. It's suppose to call a Javascript function and pass the value to the function. But it shows `Server tag not well formed` error.

I've tried looking for solutions, some said the quotes and double quotes do matter. But I've tried everything and nothing's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may consider binding onchange event on the server side by handling GridView's RowDataBound event. You will be able to bind your event as follows which is more convenient in my opinion.

```
void CustomersGridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{
   if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow) 
   {
       // Find your drop down list
       DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddlCompanyMembership");

       // Add onchange event as attribute
       ddl.Attributes["onchange"] = "verifyUser('your logic');";
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, it's working! But then, what if I would like to get the latest selected value of the dropdown? I had `alert()` in the `verifyUser()` and everytime it hits, it's alerting the populated result of the dropdown. It won't alert the selected value instead.

Comment: If you want to pass its latest value to **verifyUser** function you will need something like this: `verifyUser(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value);` This will always get the latest value of the select.

Comment: Thanks! It's finally working the way I want it to be.

Comment: Glad that it helped. Happy coding! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
onchange="verifyUser('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CCMP_CODE").ToString()%>');"
```

above code helps you to make it working.

Comment: onchange="verifyUser('<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "CCMP_CODE").ToString()%>');" Try This